# Link controls not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to control the "show more" link and cannot, I've used link controls before, but this one is puzzling me. The link I've tried to control so far is `#r_a_show_more_link` ("show more" link on right under recent activity) it's code is at the bottom of the CSS, but I can't get it to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the CSS selectors? Please look at the code and run the snippet!

Thanks a lot!

```css
/* Main Nav */
 #home_icon {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 95px;
 }

 li {
  display: inline-block;
 }

 ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 li a:link {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: times;
  font-size: 24px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }

 nav li a:visited {
  color: black;
 }

 nav li a:hover {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
 }

 nav li a:active {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
 }

 nav {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 }

 input[type=search] {
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 #searchbox {
  float: right;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #2b303b;
  border: none;
  color: #63717f;
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
 #logo {
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
 }

body {
    background-image: url("../pictures/test.jpg");
    background-color: blue;
 min-height: 500px;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

aside {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 width: 170px;
 height: 600px;
 margin: 0;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#main_content {
 width: 1000px;
 min-height: 600px;
 display: block;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 position: relative; top: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#here_you_can_learn {
 font-size: 47px;
 color: gray;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

#welcome {
 color: white;
 font-size: 130px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
}

#down_arrow {
 height: 50px;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
}

#most_frequent {
 width: 600px;
 vertical-align: top;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#m_f_heading {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}



#m_f_show_more {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}


#recent_activity {
 width: 375px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#r_a_heading {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_body {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_show_more {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#r_a_show_more_link :visited {
  color: black;
 }

#r_a_show_more_link :hover {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
 }

#r_a_show_more_link :active {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Home | Jeff's Website</title>

<link href="styles/main_navigation.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/body.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main_content.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>


<body>

<!--Main Nav-->
<header>
 <nav>
  <a href="">
   <img id="logo" src="pictures/jeff_logo.png" alt="Logo">
  </a>
  
  <a href=""><img src="pictures/home_icon.png" id="home_icon"/></a>

  <form action="" id="searchbox">
   <input id="search_input" type="search" name="searchmysite" placeholder="Search my Site!">
     <input type="submit" value="Search!">
  </form>
  
  <ul>
   <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Trips</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Misc</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>


<!--Welcome to jeff's website-->

<div>
 <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to </br> my website!</h1>
 <a href="#here_you_can_learn">
 <img src="pictures/down_arrow.png" id="down_arrow"/>
 </a>
</div>

<!--right side nav-->

<aside>
 <p>this is aside</p>

</aside>


<!--Main Content-->

<div id="main_content">
 <h2 id="here_you_can_learn">Here you can learn about me and my adventures!</h2>

<!--Most Frequently visited pages: on left side of page-->
 <div id="most_frequent">
  <p id="m_f_heading">Most frequently visted pages!</p>
  
  
  
  <a href="" id="m_f_show_more_link"><p id="m_f_show_more">Show More</p></a>
 
 </div>
 
<!--Recent Activity: on the right side of page-->
 <div id="recent_activity">
  <p id="r_a_heading">Recent Activity</p>
  
  
  <p id="r_a_body">test</p>
  
  
  <a href="" id="r_a_show_more_link"><p id="r_a_show_more">Show More</p></a>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "control the 'show more' link"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jeff F. I'm trying to remove the purple when the link has been visited, and control what happens when a user hovers over it and clicks on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the space before `:visited` in the CSS:

```
#r_a_show_more_link:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: @daniel exactly what I did in my answer :)

Comment: @dippas Yes, 20 mins after Jeff provided the answer :)

Comment: but mine is complete :), that's the difference

Comment: @dippas Thanks for the answer, I'm going with Jeff F.'s post due to the fact he was the first to comment and solve the issue. I thank for for your answer and it's completeness!

Comment: @JeffArries no worries my friend, just wanna alert you for the extra space in each link you had ;)

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra space before your  `:hover`,`:visited` and`:active`, so remove it, like this:

```css
#r_a_show_more_link:visited {
 color: black;
}
#r_a_show_more_link:hover {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}
#r_a_show_more_link:active {
  color: black;
  border-color: black;
}
```